# the login page does not moving me to the welcome page in php

Tags: php

Is this code okay? as I do not receive any errors at all.

session.php

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

// if the user is already logged in then redirect user to welcome page
if (isset($_SESSION["userid"]) && $_SESSION["userid"] === true) {
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php

require_once "config.php";
require_once "session.php";


$error = '';
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST" && isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    // validate if email is empty
    if(empty($email)) {
        $error .= '<p class="error">Please enter email.</p>';
    }

    // validate if password is empty
    if(empty($password)) {
        $error .= '<p class="error">Please enter your password.</p>';
    }

    if(empty($error)) {
        if($query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?")) {
            $query->bind_param('s', $email);
            $query->execute();
            $row = $query->fetch();
            if ($row) {
                if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
                    $_SESSION["userid"] = $row['id'];
                    $_SESSION["user"] = $row;

                    // Redirect the user to welcome page
                    header("location: welcome.php");
                    exit;
             } else {
                    $error .= '<p class="error">The password is not valid.';
                }
            } else {
                $error .= '<p class="error">No User exist with that email address.';
            }
        }
        $query->close();
    }
     // Close connection
    mysqli_close($db);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>Login</h2>
                <p>Please fill in your email and password.</p>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                    <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.php">Register here</a>.</p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

welcome.php

```
<?php
// start the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is not logged in, then redirect the user to login page
if (!isset($_SESSION["userid"]) || $_SESSION["userid"] !== true) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION["name"]; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Hello, <strong><?php echo $_SESSION["name"]; ?></strong>. Welcome to demo site.</h1>
            </div>
            <p>
                <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Log Out</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

welcome.php changed to -

```
<?php
// start the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is not logged in, then redirect the user to login page
if (empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

session.php changed to =

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

// if the user is already logged in then redirect user to welcome page
if (empty($_SESSION['user']) === false) {
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

register.php -

```
<?php

require_once "config.php";
require_once "session.php";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST" && isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $fullname = trim($_POST['name']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $confirm_password = trim($_POST['confirm_password']);
    $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    if($query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?")) {
        $error = '';

    $query->bind_param('s', $email);
    $query->execute();
    $query->store_result();
        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
            $error .= '<p class="error">The email address is already registered!</p>';
        } else {
            if (strlen($password ) < 6) {
                $error .= '<p class="error>Password must have atleast 6 characters.</p>';
            }

            // Validate confirm password
            if (empty($confirm_password)) {
                $error .= '<p class="error">Please enter confirm password.</p>';
            } else {
                if (empty($error) && ($password != $confirm_password)) {
                    $error .= '<p class="error">Password did not match.</p>';
                }
            }
            if (empty($error) ) {
                $insertQuery = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?);");
                $insertQuery->bind_param("sss", $fullname, $email, $password_hash);
                $result = $insertQuery->execute();
                if ($result) {
                    $error .= '<p class="success">Your registration was successful!</p>';
                } else {
                    $error .= '<p class="error">Something went wrong!</p>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $query->close();
    $insertQuery->close();
    // Close DB connection
    mysqli_close($db);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Signup</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>Register</h2>
                <p>Please fill this form to create an account.</p>
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Full Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                    <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.php">Login Here</a>.</p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

logout.php -

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

// Destroy the session.
if (session_destroy()) {
    // redirect to the login page
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
define('DBSERVER', 'localhost'); // Database server
define('DBUSERNAME', 'root'); // Database username
define('DBPASSWORD', ''); // Database password
define('DBNAME', 'demo'); // Database name

/* connect to MySQL database */
$db = mysqli_connect(DBSERVER, DBUSERNAME, DBPASSWORD, DBNAME);

// check db connection
if($db === false){
    die("Error: connection error. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

db.sql - that connects to the server verifed it adds to the database using phpmyadmin so the registration is working.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(7255) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
)   ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

EDIT: added the changes to the session.php + welcome.php + added the whole files of the whole code.

Comment: You're storing the user id in `$_SESSION["userid"]`, but then you check if it contains a boolean:  `$_SESSION["userid"] !== true` will always evaulate as true, redirecting you back to the login page. You could skip the `userid` completely since you have the whole user in `user`. An easier check would then be `if (empty($_SESSION['user'])) { ..your redirect.. }`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I changed it in session and in welcome but than it was not working as it was always refreshing, than I only changed it in session.php correct? where did you mean to change it? as I mentioned already even in only changing it in session.php it is looping(always refreshing...) also only changing welcome making it not working as the first "error" = "tried to login it does only a refresh of the login page and That is it."

Comment: You should change it in both places since both are specifically comparing the value against a boolean. In session.php, change it to: `if (empty($_SESSION['user']) === false)` (will redirect to welcome if session is set and not empty) and in welcome.php, change it to: `if (empty($_SESSION['user']))` (will redirect to login if session is not set and/or empty)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson still not working. (the login page still refreshing itself...)

Comment: Are you sure that the authentication actually works and that there wasn't some error or invalid credentials? I can see that you populate `$error` but you never output it anywhere. Also check the web servers error log to see if you don't get any errors/warnings that could mess things up. It would also help if you edited your question and added the changes you've done (don't change the original code, add the updates in the end instead) so we can see if the changes looks correct.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson added the changes + the whole code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson also, there is no errors at all.

Comment: You forgot the first question: _"Are you sure that the authentication actually works and that there wasn't some error or invalid credentials? I can see that you populate $error but you never output it anywhere."_

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes. and there is no errors like I said.